# Filter clipboard and save as data list

Tags: applescript, clipboard

I'm trying to get an AppleScript to find somme keyword from the clipboard and list them in a new clipboard

e.g : I copy this line in the clipboard "order KAFGEFEF price 999 date 17 order KADFSDGS price 874 date 18"`

and the result will be

```
K1AFGE2FEF
K1ADFSD2GS
```

or even beter

```
K1AFGE2FEF : 999
K1ADFSD2GS : 17
```

the data I want to collect always start with "K1...." and have 10 characteres.

I actually had a old Javascript which are kind of doing the trick but I need to use AppleScript instead.

I really not sure where to start here, maybe I shoud start something around pbcopy and egrep ?

hope that's make sense.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question exactly how your clipboard data is structured or what your desired output is. For starters, here is an Applescript solution that will extract order, price, and date values from the clipboard. It assumes that order, price, and date are always grouped together in that specific order, and that there can be multiple order-price-date groups in a single line of text on the clipboard. For example:

```
order K1AFGE2FEF price 999 date 17 order K1ADFSD2GS price 874 date 18
```

Then the following Applescript will extract each order, price, and date triplet and save it as a three-item sublist in a master list:

```
set masterList to {}
set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
try
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "order "
    repeat with i in (get (the clipboard)'s text items 2 thru -1)
        tell i's contents
            try
                set currOrder to first word
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "price "
                set currPrice to (get its text item 2)'s first word
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "date "
                set currDate to (get its text item 2)'s first word
                if (currOrder starts with "K1") and (currOrder's length = 10) then set end of masterList to {currOrder, currPrice, currDate}
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
end try
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
return masterList -- {{"K1AFGE2FEF", "999", "17"}, {"K1ADFSD2GS", "874", "18"}}
```

The master list can then be processed further into whatever output you desire.